# JavaScript countdown doesn't work in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using countdown. For unknown reason the countdown doesn't appear in Safari. It does work perfectly fine in Chrome, Opera and IE. Link to the countdown can be found [here](http://designbycolor.co.uk/test) Did someone experience the same issue?

Please find link to my JS Countdown: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/048fa888e04b0981b207c48d674272fa

Comment: The problem is not related to Bootstrap. It's mainly about the JavaScript countdown library which you are using.

Comment: Churix do you have an idea what in my JS would cause it to not appear in Safari?

Comment: I can suggest you that use timestamp for date variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your main.js . Safari cannot create valid date object with  24:00:00. Try this :

```
var endDate = "May 01, 2016 00:00:00";
```